# Serializer for writing Foreign Keys as integer id but reading them as object

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have two models - ***Users*** and ***UserAccessLogs***:

```
class Users(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.Charfield()
    etc.

class UserAccessLogs(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    anotherField = models.Charfield()
    etc.
```

with serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_email(self, value):
        # validations here

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.email = validated_data['email'] 
        etc.
        instance.save()
        return instance

class UserAccessLogsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAccessLogs
        fields ='__all__'
```

In my views function I would like to retrieve the actual user class when fetching ***UserAccessLogs*** i.e. I would like:

```
UserAccessLogs = {
   user : {
           email: myEmail,
           name: myName, 
           etc.
          }
}
```

instead of

```
UserAccessLogs = {
   user : 1
}
```

in my views:

```
access_logs = UserAccessLogs.objects.all()
serializer = UserAccessLogsSerializer(access_logs, many = True)
return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I tried adding `user = UserSerializer()` to ***UserAccessLogsSerializer*** class. It works, but then when I try and save a new instance of the ***UserAccessLogs*** I get errors related to **User** model from the validators. If I set `read_only = True` then it leaves *user = null* in the database. The below works in my views class but it doesn't seem efficient and needs to be repeated every time I want to get *full* UserAccessLogs.

```
for data in serializer.data:
      data['user'] = UserSerializer(User.objects.get(id = data['user'])).data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
user_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), source='user')
```

Comment: Thanks, I used something like this in the end:

`user = UserSerializer(read_only = True)
 user_pk = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = User.objects.all(), source = 'user', write_only = True, allow_null = True)` and then used `user_pk ` when inserting and `user` when reading.

Answer (score 0):

create two serializers in `serializer.py`

```
class User_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = '__all__'
    
class User_access_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAccessLogs
        fields = '__all__'
    user = User_serializer()
```

in you `API`:

```
UserAccessLogs_queryset = UserAccessLogs.objects.all()
serializer_class = User_access_serializer(UserAccessLogs_queryset ,many=True)
return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

it will create `nested API` as you needed

> Also i assume you have an error doing class `UserAccessLogs`
> by  `(AbstractUser)` it looks like you need `class UserAccessLogs(models.Model):`

Comment: Hi, I'm confused to how your code is different to mine. I did mention:

I tried adding user = UserSerializer() to UserAccessLogsSerializer class. It works, but then when I try and save a new instance of the UserAccessLogs I get errors related to User model from the validators.

Comment: it means problem is not about `nested serializer`, but problem with `validators`. You need to create different theme then, this topic name is `Nested Serializer for Foreign Keys`, and my solution solve it

Comment: also if the problem with `validators` you should provide an error code, in order to solve it, so this topic should be losed

Comment: When I try and save a UserAccessLogs object, I **don't** want to also save a User object. The validators are working fine saying that the user already exists. The problem is that with this method it appears to try and save a User instance also. I only want to read the User foreign key as a User object.

Comment: this is because there is update method in your `UserSerializer` >> `delete it`, and bring out business logic in `views.py`